# Getting start and end id of highlighted/selected <span> over multiple <span> and <div> elements

Tags: javascript, html

Apologies if this has been answered before. I'm trying to get the user's highlighted elements with window.getSelection(), but my text is constructed from a list of  in a  like this:

```html
<div id="div1">
  <span id="span1">Word1</span>
  <span id="span2">Word2</span>
  <span id="span3">Word3</span>
</div>
<div id="div2">
  <span id="span4">Word1</span>
  <span id="span5">Word2</span>
  <span id="span6">Word3</span>
</div>
```

Currently, though, window.getSelection only returns the first span object when I test it in the Chrome console.

I want to be able to identify the beginning span id and the end span id of the selection - so if I highlighted the entire block, I would expect some tuple ("span1","span6"). Would really appreciate any help! Thanks so much.

Comment: One (maybe unrelated) issue is that you're not closing your HTML tags correctly. You should be using `</span>` and `</div>`

Comment: @NickParsons Right - made a mistake typing it up in the question editor, thanks for the catch! Question still stands though!

Comment: Could you maybe added your code which uses `window.getSelection`, that way people can help you rewrite it/debug it

Comment: isn't your beginning span id is `span1` and end span id is `span3`? your expected tuple is confusing?